# Explanation about the code(palindromic partitioning of strings without cuts)

Tags: java, string, recursion, palindrome

Given a string s, partition s such that every string of the partition is a palindrome. Return all possible palindrome partitioning of s.

Example :

```
Input  : s = "bcc"
Output : [["b", "c", "c"], ["b", "cc"]]
```

Here's the solution:

```
public class GFG {     

    // Prints the partition list
    static void printSolution(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> partitions) {
        for(ArrayList<String> i: partitions) {
            for(String j: i) {
                System.out.print(j+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> addStrings(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> v, String s, ArrayList<String> temp, int index) {
        int len = s.length();
        String str = "";
        ArrayList<String> current = new ArrayList<>(temp);

        if (index == 0)
        temp.clear();

        for (int i = index; i < len; ++i) {
            str = str + s.charAt(i);
            if (checkPalindrome(str)) {
                temp.add(str);
                if (i + 1 < len) {    
                    v = addStrings(v,s,temp,i+1);
                } else {
                    v.add(temp);
                }

                // temp is reinitialize with the 
                // current i.
                temp = new ArrayList<>(current);
            }
        }
        return v;
    }

    static void partition(String s, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> v) {
        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        v = addStrings(v, s, temp, 0);
        printSolution(v);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s = "geeks";
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> partitions = new
        ArrayList<>();
        partition(s, partitions);
    }
}
```

Here I am not able to understand how the string "ee" has been formed. Can someone please explain to me the code and how recursion is been used under loop.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider how the program works for the string "geeks".

When the function `partition` is called initially, it calls `addStrings` function to find out all the partitions.

Let's have a look at the `addString` function:

```
static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> addStrings(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> v, String s, ArrayList<String> temp, int index) {
    int len = s.length();
    String str = "";
    ArrayList<String> current = new ArrayList<>(temp);

    if (index == 0)
    temp.clear();

    for (int i = index; i < len; ++i) {
        str = str + s.charAt(i);
        if (checkPalindrome(str)) {
            temp.add(str);
            if (i + 1 < len) {    
                v = addStrings(v,s,temp,i+1);
            } else {
                v.add(temp);
            }

            // temp is reinitialize with the 
            // current i.
            temp = new ArrayList<>(current);
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

It creates an arraylist with the same content as that of temp, and a variable to hold the current partition we are checking `str`. For the first call, index will be 0, so the loop goes from `0 to len`, and in its first iteration 'g' gets added to `str`.

Since, a single letter is a palindrome of its own, it gets added to `temp`, now `(i+1)` is less than `len`, so we recursively call `addStrings`, with `i+1`, to start looking for partitions from the next index.

Each of these first few calls will add single-letter strings to `temp`, and recursively call `addStrings`. This happens until 's' is added to temp.

For 's', `(i+1) = len` `(index is 4)`, so no more further recursion, instead `temp` is added to `v`, that is all single-letter palindromes are generated.

Now recursion backtracks, `(index is 3)` and the statement `v = addStrings(v, s, temp, i+1)` has got executed. Now `temp` is re-initialized with `current`, because we have already added all single-letter palindromes to `v`. Now `str` will change from `k` to `ks`, in the next iteration, and since it is not a palindrome this call will also return.

This will continue until `(index=1)`, as both "ek" and "eks" are not palindrome, so nothing much will happen at `(index=2)`.

For `(index=1)`, when the recursion bactracks `str` will be `e` initially, and it will become `ee` on the next iteration, and since it is a palindrome, its gets added to `temp` and finally to `v`. Rest all the strings `eek`, `eeks`, `ge`, `gee`, `geek`, and `geeks`, are not palindromes and won't show up in the output.

Hopefully, now you get how 'ee' is formed.